# Generating Google managed Wildcard SSL Certificates

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to generate a Google managed Wildcard SSL certificates, by reading through this guide https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/deploy-google-managed-dns-auth#create_a_google-managed_certificate_referencing_the_dns_authorization, I was not able to create a certificate as I am not sure what should I insert in the AUTHORIZATION_NAME. What should I insert in the Cloud Shell to complete this command:
gcloud certificate-manager certificates create "sit-cert-google"     --domains=*.test.sit, test.sit"
--dns-authorizations=

? Thank you!

By inserting this gcloud certificate-manager certificates create "sit-cert-google"     --domains="*.sit.chocolatefactory.app, *.sit.forty2.cloud, sit.chocolatefactory.app, sit.forty2.cloud, test.forty2.cloud"     --dns-authorizations=test.cloud., where "test.cloud." is the DNS name, I get this error ERROR: (gcloud.certificate-manager.certificates.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Validation failed

- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:

  - description: dns authorization doesn't exist
    field: managed.dns_authorizations[0]

Comment: Use Google to find help on Google products.... (for example: https://www.google.com/search?q=dns+authorization+doesn%27t+exist+field%3A+managed.dns_authorizations%5B0%5D )

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/dns-authorizations